# Calculating last and third value difference of each same column value in a dataframe in loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to calculate the difference between the last and third value for specific month and year for each column (ex1, ex2,...) in my dataset and then save into new dataframe.

My **dataset** looks like this:

| month | year | ex1 | ex2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1995 | 55 | 55 |
| 12 | 1995 | 46 | 33 |
| 12 | 1995 | **33** | **12** |
| 12 | 1995 | 15 | 17 |
| 12 | 1995 | 6 | 16 |
| 12 | 1995 | 35 | 32 |
| 12 | 1995 | 67 | 22 |
| 12 | 1995 | 43 | 25 |
| 12 | 1995 | 31 | 26 |
| 12 | 1995 | 34 | 11 |
| 12 | 1995 | 53 | 14 |
| 12 | 1995 | **72** | **60** |
| 1 | 1996 | 34 | 90 |
| 1 | 1996 | 55 | 14 |
| 1 | 1996 | **58** | **24** |
| 1 | 1996 | 54 | 23 |
| 1 | 1996 | 33 | 20 |
| 1 | 1996 | 24 | 45 |
| 1 | 1996 | 23 | 33 |
| 1 | 1996 | 15 | 38 |
| 1 | 1996 | 11 | 50 |
| 1 | 1996 | 79 | 55 |
| 1 | 1996 | 80 | 71 |
| 1 | 1996 | **88** | **74** |

So for example, I want to calculate for **ex1**:

- Last value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 72
- Third value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 33
- Difference: 72 - 33 = 39
- Last value of month 1 and year 1996 -> 88
- Third value of month 1 and year 1996 -> 58
- Difference: 88 - 58 = 30

For **ex2**:

- Last value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 88
- Third value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 58
- Difference: 88 - 58 = 30
- Last value of month 1 and year 1996 -> 74
- Third value of month 1 and year 1996 -> 24
- Difference: 74 - 24 = 50

After that, I want to write these values a new dataframe as follow:

| Name | Month | Year | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ex1 | 12 | 1995 | 39 |
| ex1 | 1 | 1996 | 30 |
| ex2 | 12 | 1995 | 30 |
| ex2 | 1 | 1996 | 50 |

I tried to do the following:

```
df = pd.read_excel ('dataset') #See above
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name","Month","Year","Difference"])

for colname, colitems in df.iloc.[:,2:].iteritems():
    for rownum, rowitem in colitems.iteritems():

        if (df["month"][rownum] != df["month"][rownum+1]) & (df["year"][rownum] != df["year"][rownum+1]):
            last= df[colname][rownum]
            third= df[colname][2]
            diff = last - third
            df_new.assign(name = df[colname][rownum], month = df["month"][rownum], 
                                    year= df["year"][rownum], difference= diff)
```

When I try to run this, I had the **KeyError: 79** in the **if** clause.

Also, my code calculates the difference only for month 12 and year 1995 for **ex1**. How can I move on to next month and year and the next value: **ex2**. Am I in the right direction? Do you have any suggestions that would help my problem?

If there's anything I've left out that would be helpful to solving this, please let me know so I can rectify it immediately.

Comment: I trust you made some typological-like errors in your first example for `ex2`. You write: `Last value of month 1 and year 1996 -> 88` and mean: `Last value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 60` and `Third value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 58` should be: `Third value of month 12 and year 1995 -> 12` and then onwards: `diff == 48` (not 30). Correct?

Comment: Hi @ouroboros1, yes there was an error and I fixed it. Thank you for warning me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic operation you are looking for is a one-liner:

```
res = df.groupby(['month','year']).last() - df.groupby(['month','year']).nth(2)
print(res)

            ex1  ex2
month year          
1     1996   30   50
12    1995   39   48
```

To get this into the shape of your desired output, try as follows:

```
res.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)
res.sort_values(['year','month'], inplace=True)

res = pd.melt(res, 
              id_vars=['month','year'], 
              value_vars=['ex1','ex2'], 
              var_name = 'name', 
              value_name='difference')

res = res.loc[:, ['name','month','year','difference']]
print(res)

  name  month  year  difference
0  ex1     12  1995          39
1  ex1      1  1996          30
2  ex2     12  1995          48
3  ex2      1  1996          50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grp = df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])
```

Then the following will return the differences you desire,

```
grp.last() - grp.nth(2)
```

No looping required :)

EDIT: here is the synonymous example I tested -- the answer is not to the requested shape, but the data is good

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "month": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "year": [1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000],
        "ex1": [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 22, 44, 66, 88, 1010, 1212, 1414, 1616],
        "ex2": [22, 44, 66, 88, 1010, 1212, 1414, 1616, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88],
    }
)
```

Returns the following:

```
>>>         
            ex1  ex2
month year
1     1999   11   22
      2000   22   11
2     1999   11  202
      2000  202   11
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea but this would calculate only the first month and year for ex1. I need two loops for further calculations (one for go through the rows and other for the columns ex1,ex2,...)

Comment: This answer is the same as mine, it's just not yet in the shape you requested.